# How to call any Navigation.PushPopupAsync from CustomViewCell in Xamarin Form?

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` and which is having `CustomViewCell`. `CustomViewCell` having few buttons.

Button: ShowProfile: This button popup another page. The problem is I don't know how to `Navigation.PushPopupAsync` in `CustomViewCell`. I also need to pass current CustomViewCell details in that.

This is example how I use `Navigation.PushPopupAsync` in another page which is working fine but doesn't work in case of CustomViewCell.

```
Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new UserProfilePage(new ExtendedProfile(_viewModel.Profile)));
```

But above code doesn't work in `CustomViewCell`.

```
public partial class ProfileListItemViewCell : CustomViewCell
{
    public ProfileListItemViewCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged ()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged ();
    }
    private void MenuItemProfile_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //not working
        Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new UserProfilePage(new ExtendedProfile(_viewModel.Profile)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `PushModalAsync` ? That push a modal page. Or use **events** in your `CustomViewCell` that are captured by the **owner page**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

> Xamarin.Forms *MessagingCenter* enables view models and other components
>   to communicate with without having to know anything about each other
>   besides a simple Message contract.

**In your Page Constructor**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SomeObject> (this, "MyAwesomeShowWindowMessage", 
(someObject) =>
{
     Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new UserProfilePage(new ExtendedProfile(someObject)));
});
```

**From your Cell**

```
 MessagingCenter.Send(SomeObject, "MyAwesomeShowWindowMessage");
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe when you exit your Listening Page for good

```
 MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<SomeObject> (this, "MyAwesomeShowWindowMessage"));
```

**Some further examples**

[How to use Xamarin.Forms Messaging Center](https://montemagno.com/how-to-use-xamarinforms-messaging-center/)

Answer (score 1):

You say your `ListView`'s `ViewCell`s each contain buttons, and one button in each `ViewCell` should be a 'view profile' button. Therefore, assuming each `ViewCell` represents a user or whatever, you can access the binding context of that particular cell in the event handler, like so (lets say the collection bound to your `ListView` is of type `List<ProfileClass>`):

```
private void MenuItemProfile_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var profile = (ProfileClass)((View)sender).BindingContext;
    // Now you can use the 'profile' object to show the pop up.
}
```